# Is there a way to remove duplicates in a multi dimensional array in Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I know that you can use the `uniq` filter in liquid but this seems to flatten the array which is not what I want.

Here's an example of my array:

```
[
  ["Brazil", "/assets/images/flags/brazil.png"], 
  ["Brazil", "/assets/images/flags/brazil.png"],
  ["Argentina", "/assets/images/flags/argentina.png"]
]
```

If I reassign the array with the `uniq` filter as below I get the following results:

```
{% assign countries = countries | uniq %}
```

Array becomes:

```
["Brazil", "/assets/images/flags/brazil.png", "Brazil", "/assets/images/flags/brazil.png", "Argentina", "/assets/images/flags/argentina.png"]
```

How can I remove the duplicate and keep the current structure of my array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this with the following liquid:

```
{% assign contacts = include.contacts %}
{% assign countries = '' | split: '' %}
{% for item in contacts %}
    {% assign array_item = '' | split: '' %}
    {% assign array_item = array_item | push: item.country %}
    {% assign array_item = array_item | push: item.country_flag_image %}

    {% unless countries contains array_item %}
        {% assign countries = countries | push: array_item %}
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

For each iteration within the `for` loop I create a new array object which contains both the country, and flag image as array items. Before adding this new array to the countries array I check whether it already exists with the `unless` statement. If it doesn't exist it gets added to the countries array.

If there's a better solution please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Another solution : using "group by" in case your array has labels :

```
{% assign alldocs = site.documents %}   
{% assign alldocsbytitle = alldocs | group_by: 'title' %}   
{% assign alldocswithoutduplicates = '' | split: '' %}
{% for docs in alldocsbytitle %}
    {% assign alldocswithoutduplicates = alldocswithoutduplicates | push: docs.items[0] %}
{% endfor %}
```